# google maps api cannot read placesservice

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

I am having a problem with Google's Maps API and its PlacesService. Even though I have the places library properly loaded it keeps saying "Cannot read property 'PlacesService' of undefined". The map itself works and loads. Any ideas? Here's the code:

```
<div id="map-canvas"></div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&libraries=place‌s"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var myLatlng;
    var map;
    var marker;

    function initialize() {
        myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(fooLat, fooLng);

        var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 17,
            center: myLatlng,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
            scrollwheel: false,
            draggable: true
        };

        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

        var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);

        var request = { placeId: 'fooPlaceId'};
        service.getDetails(request, callback);

        function callback (place, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
                marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: place.position,
                    map: map,
                    title: place.name
                });
            }
        };
    }

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
```

Update:
I literally just tried a piece of code [from Google itself](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/place-details) and it gave me the same error.

Comment: If you have an answer, please post it as an answer and [accept it](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) rather than editing the question.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Here's the answer: I copied the include line directly from some page (either here, stackoverflow, or one of Googles APIs example pages. What seems to be the problem is that it, for whatever reason, had an invisible character in the name of the library which mine CMS editor didn't pick up on. So beware when copying!

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted - if you copy the OP's 'libraries' querystring parameter you end up with three invisible characters between the "e" and the "s" of "places": E2, 80 and 8C in hex. I was not expecting that!

Answer (score 31):

This example requires the Places library. Include the `libraries=places` parameter when you first load the API with API Key.

For example:

`<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=places">`

Comment: Note: If you need multiple libraries enabled just separate them with comma - e.g. `&libraries=geometry,places`

Answer (score 0):

for me the issue was i didn't do `.bind(this)` to the callback function of the service